# Filter JSON based on some values in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter my JSON in such a way that I only want to have data with `"category": 'two'`.

Data:

```
var json = [
             {"id": 1,
              "category":'one'; 
             }
             {"id": 1,
              "category":'two'; 
             }
             {"id": 1,
              "category":'two'; 
             }
             {"id": 1,
              "category":'three'; 
             }
           ]
```

Comment: Please learn [the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Comment: @str, that's not even an array of objects. It's just one big syntax error.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data  is not valid. Objects inside an array and each key-value pair should be separated by comma (`,`). Correct that then use `filter()`:

```js
var json = [{"id": 1,
  "category":'one' 
  },{"id": 1,
  "category":'two' 
  },{"id": 1,
  "category":'two' 
  },{"id": 1,
  "category":'three'
  }
]
var res = json.filter(i => i.category == 'two');
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I tried the filter method, it gives me an error as json.filter is not a function

Comment: @abhi have you also fixed the syntax?

Comment: @abhi, then *json* is not an array...

Comment: yes, does the value has to be in single quotes, I have value in double quotes

Comment: @abhi no, the problem is that you had random `;` and missing `,`. Check what Mamun wrote with what you have.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I did fixed that, that was typo error while posting the question, sorry for that

Comment: actually the data i have is a output of redis cache key

Comment: it works after doing `JSON.parse(josn)`